# How to setup matplotlib to work with Django framework (python)

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I have already created my project in Django and have tested it locally. I'm wondering how I can add matplotlib to my Django project so that I can import it in my view.py.

I've had major issues setting up matplotlib in Windows, but now I'm working with Anaconda, which is pre-packaged with matplotlib. Although I can test my matplotlib code in Anaconda, I have no idea how to setup the matplotlib in Django framework so that I can test it in the server.

Thanks in advance for any help or direction.

Comment: I don't work with django much, so I apologize if this is a dumb question, but can't you just import it like any other module once it's installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I finally managed to solve the problem.

My path was set to Python rather than Anaconda. I deleted the old path from Environment Variables, replaced it with the path of Anaconda.

After I did this, I realized Anaconda doesn't have Django framework installed. In Spider, I went to Tools >> Open Command Prompt and wrote this command to install it (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/django):

```
conda install -c anaconda django=1.9.5
```

Now I can run the server using Python through Anaconda which already has matplotlib library, therefore everything works fine, and I get no exception errors.

Thanks Paul H.